# Why does AES in python take so long?

Tags: python-3.x

When i try to encrypt this 2.2MB file, it takes forever for the program to do this.\
Here is the code:

```
import pyaes
import os

key = os.urandom(16)
IV = os.urandom(16)

aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCBC(key, IV)
encrypt = pyaes.Encrypter(aes)

with open("file", "rb") as file:
    data = file.read()

encrypted = encrypt.feed(data)
encrypted += encrypt.feed()

print(encrypted)
```

I heard that AES can encrypt 1GB in 0.6 seconds on a 2.2GHZ clock CPU

Is this because python is a slow language in general or am i missing something out?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that AES library. Have you tried any other implementations (e.g. [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/))?

Comment: not really, i shall try now

Comment: I just tried using the cryptography module and it successfully worked, the only problem is that my whole project is implemented using the pyaes module and its a quite big project

Comment: Was the cryptography version significantly faster?

Comment: it was instant, whereas the other took more than 5 mins

Comment: Im sure my current one should be able to do it that fast im just implementing it in the wrong way